# Why doesn't \b\w+\b match a word?

Tags: python, regex

Why does the following Python statement return `None`?

```
>>> re.match('\b\w+\b', 'foo')
>>>
```

As far as I understand, that should match the word `foo`. The first `\b` should match the beginning of the word `foo`, `\w+` should match the word `foo`, and the final `\b` should match the end of the word `foo`. What is wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't escape backslash in `\b`, `\b` matches backspace, not word boundary.

```
>>> '\b'    # BACKSPACE, not \ + b
'\x08'
>>> '\\b'   # \ + b
'\\b'
>>> r'\b'   # raw string literal (r'\b' == '\\b')
'\\b'

>>> re.match('\b\w+\b', 'foo')
>>> re.match(r'\b\w+\b', 'foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002C18100>
```

Comment: more on [Regular expression HOWTO / More-metacharacters](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters)